# How to create a single data tile in azure application insight dashboard?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, dashboard

How to create a single data tile in azure application insight dashboard ?
by single data i mean the XXX(A number)(which i found querying the application insights).

For say - I queried for unique users in Application Insight logs, and I want to display it as Single Data Tile on the Dashboard. i.e. just the number(XXX) and the heading (Unique Users For XYZ Application)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try the code below, then pin to dashboard:

```
requests 
//add the filter for querying unique users
| extend users=""
| summarize number_of_users = count() by users
| render barchart
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: hi, i was able to do it but i want to pin a single data tile on the dashboard. Exploring Workbook option, still no leads how to do it. any idea how can we do that with workbook.

Comment: @AarushiSinghal, could you please let me know what's single data tile?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E65859_01/fluid_ux/images/tiles/image017.png this link will give you an idea about the data tile i want

Comment: I think it does not support, but I will confirm with others and let you know the result.

Comment: can you try to resize the tile to 1x1 or 2x1 etc.? If that not help, you can submit a suggestion for this, link is [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/357324-application-insights)

Answer (score 0):

Workbooks will give you tons of features to create custom tiles showing just the number on the tile. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67685647/show-a-value-only-in-a-dashboard-in-azure/67738944#67738944) how to do it using Workbooks.