# Show a value only in a dashboard in azure?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-log-analytics

I have following query:

```
AppMetrics | where Name=="ReportImported"| summarize Value=count()
```

I would like to show the value in a dashboard, and it looks like this:

[image]

Is there anyway to only display the number and not having it displayed as a list with a Value column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an Azure Monitor Workbooks to achieve this.

1. From your Azure Portal, go to Monitor and look for Workbooks on the left pane. Then click **New** to create a new Workbook, followed by the **Add query** button.

[image]

2. At this point you can already paste your query in the query console window.  Select your Log Analytics Workspace and make sure to run the query to validate it works. Under the **Visualization** drop-down, choose **Tiles** and a new **Tiles settings** will appear on the right. Click on that to bring up the settings page.

[image]

3. Here the only thing I configured was the **Left** Tile field. Set your values accordingly and check the **custom formatting** box. Click **Apply** to see the changes reflect. You can explore other features here and then click on **Done editing** if you're satisfied. Finally, click on **Done editing** and save your workbook.

[image]

4. Now for the next step, the Workbook needs to be in edit mode again. Edit it and then click on the Pin icon. A pop-up shows up, explaining two options you have for pinning. Look to the right you'll see another 'item-level' pin. Click on that and choose your dashboard.

[image]

5. It should show up in your dashboard with the Workbook name as the title and a number as the only content of the tile.

[image]

It might seem a bit complex but that's the only method I found today, after struggling for a solution for a few weeks. [Workbooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/visualize/workbooks-tile-visualizations) are very powerful and allow for very rich visualization!

Comment: Time based filtering is not working in dashboard after using this method. Is it as expected?

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a suitable tile in the Tile Gallery that can do this straight out of the box. There is a similar open idea on [User Voice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/223579-azure-portal/suggestions/38765962-add-azure-log-analytics-in-tile-gallery-from-dashb).

The closest I could get to doing something similar is by using the [Workbooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/visualize/workbooks-overview) feature in Azure Monitor, that would look like this when pinned to the dashboard:

[image: Workbok Tile]

Here are the steps to create the above visual:

1. Navigate to your Log Analytics Workspace
2. Create a new workbook > Add query
3. Add your log analytics query and run a preview
4. Configure the [Tile settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/visualize/view-designer-conversion-tiles#number--list-tile) as follows:

   - Change the **Visualization** dropdown to **Tiles** and then select **Tile Settings**.
   - Set the **Title** and select **Left**. Change the value for **Use column:** to **Count**, and **Column Renderer** to **Big Number**.

After saving the query step but before saving the workbook, select the pin option and pin this query step to your Azure dashboard as follows:

[image: Pin to Dashboard]

With this approach, you can leverage a range of [visualization options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/visualize/workbooks-tile-visualizations) and features that Azure Monitor Workbooks offer, creating rich visual reports and interactive experiences.

Comment: I've successfully added the tile to my dashboard but it doesn't seem to update. Only when I open the workbook, the data on the dashboard is updated. Does your tile behave the same?